# SQL query to return data from bridging table returning error (likely due to my query syntax!)

Tags: python, mysql, database, flask

I'm having issues with my SQL query to get any data out of my database using python/flask (probably due to the fact that I'm relatively new to MySQL and my query syntax is likely to be terrible!).

I'm trying to get data out of my bridging table from the database as it's been created below:

```
CREATE TABLE student (
student_id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name varchar (20) NOT NULL,
last_name varchar (20) NOT NULL,
year_began int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (student_id)
);

CREATE TABLE courses (
course_code varchar (7) NOT NULL,
course_title varchar (100) NOT NULL,
year_delivered int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (course_code)
);

CREATE TABLE enrollments (
student_id int NOT NULL,
course_code varchar (7) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT enrollment PRIMARY KEY (student_id, course_code),
FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES student (student_id),
FOREIGN KEY (course_code) REFERENCES courses (course_code) 
);
```

My current python code including my query currently is written like this:

```
        student_name = str(request.form['student_name_search'])
        student_name = ' '.join(student_name.split())

        try:
            cursor = mydb.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT student_id, first_name, last_name FROM student AND course_code FROM courses\
            LEFT JOIN enrollments on student_id=student_id LEFT JOIN course_code=course_code WHERE\
                (CONCAT(first_name,last_name ) LIKE '%{}%')".format(student_name))
            search_result = cursor.fetchall()
            cursor.close()
            return render_template('studentselect_results.html', student_name = student_name)


        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            cursor.close()
            return failure('studentsearch',f"Error message: {err}. Search didn't work")
```

The HTML for where the search criteria is entered into is below:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('process_searchstudent') }}" method="POST">
            <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-12">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="student_name_search" name="student_name_search" 
                        placeholder="Enter Students Name">
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div>   
            <!-- SUMBIT/RESET BUTTONS-->
            <div class="form-row justify-content-center">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" value="Search">
                        <input type="button" id="resetBtn" class="btn btn-outline-danger" value="Reset">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

The HTML where I'm hoping for the query to return data to is below:

```
<table class="table table-sm table-striped">
        <thread class="thread-light">
            <tr>
                <th>Student ID:</th>
                <th>Student First Name:</th>
                <th>Student Last Name:</th>
                <th>Click to View Student Details</th>
            </tr>
        </thread>
        <tbody>
            {% for each_result in search_results %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{item[0]}}</td>
                <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
                <td>{{item[2]}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

When the "search" button is clicked on the first HTML page it get the following error:

*Error message: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND course_code FROM courses LEFT JOIN enrollments on student_id=stud' at line 1. Search didn't work*

Any and all help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the correct syntax for a `JOIN` query. Try this instead:

```
SELECT s.student_id, s.first_name, s.last_name , c.course_code
FROM student s
LEFT JOIN enrollments e on e.student_id = s.student_id
JOIN courses c ON c.course_code = e.course_code 
WHERE CONCAT(s.first_name, s.last_name) LIKE '%{}%'
```

Comment: Thanks @Nick, but the HTML table that I'm wanting the data into returns empty.  Any ideas why it's not returning anything??

Comment: @halma562 your `LIKE` clause looks odd - what fills in the `{}` value?

Comment: this should be filled in with `.format(student_name))` at the end of the query where student_name is created at the top of the python script 
`student_name = str(request.form['student_name_search'])
student_name = ' '.join(student_name.split())
`

Comment: Is there any way of checking whether the query returned any results at all  (I'm presuming it didn't get an error since you have an `except` block)

Comment: If I run the query directly in MySQL and replace the `{}` with a string, say `"cor"` it runs the query without any problems and returns the expected results

Comment: It doesn't look like you're actually passing the results to `render_template`, shouldn't it be `render_template('studentselect_results.html', search_results = search_result)`?

Comment: Also `{{item[0]}}` should probably be `{{each_result[0]}}` or change `{% for each_result in search_results %}` to `{% for item in search_results %}`

Comment: Changed code so it's now passing the results to `render_template` correctly and changed the other code to `{% for item in search_results %}` but it's still coming back with a blank table?

Comment: @halma562 I'm afraid that is beyond the limits of my expertise as well as outside the scope of the original question. I think you should probably start a new question.